# Create a longer line segment from a shorter one?

Tags: geometry, geopandas, turf, mathematics

I do not believe my math is incorrect. This is seems like it could be a projection issue.

I start with the following two coordinates ( lon, lat in degrees )

a: [37.821055535000085, -46.84417083099993]
b: [37.89112389400009, -46.64967213299991]

When visualized with geopandas, the `lineSegment` defined by the points looks like:

```
path = 'data.geo.json'
data = json.load( open( path, "r" ) )
gdf = geopandas.GeoDataFrame.from_features( data, crs = 4326 )
```

[image: base line segment]

What is drawn here is correct.

I want to extend this line segment in both directions and draw the perpendicular line segment.

To do this, I am using turf and some math:

```
  const direction = [b[0] - a[0], b[1] - a[1]]
  const length = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(direction[0], 2) + Math.pow(direction[1], 2))

  direction[0] = direction[0] / length
  direction[1] = direction[1] / length

  const b2 = [a[0] + direction[0] * length, a[1] + direction[1] * length]

  const lineSegment = turf.lineString([a, b2])

  const perpendicularDirection = [-direction[1], direction[0]]
  const boxDiagonalLength = length * 2
  let boxPoint = a

  const iFactor = direction[0] * boxDiagonalLength
  const jFactor = direction[1] * boxDiagonalLength
  const normalLineEndA = [boxPoint[0] + iFactor, boxPoint[1] + jFactor]
  const normalLineEndB = [boxPoint[0] - iFactor, boxPoint[1] - jFactor]
  const normalLine = turf.lineString([normalLineEndA, normalLineEndB])

  const piFactor = perpendicularDirection[0] * boxDiagonalLength
  const pjFactor = perpendicularDirection[1] * boxDiagonalLength
  const pNormalLineEndA = [boxPoint[0] + piFactor, boxPoint[1] + pjFactor]
  const pNormalLineEndB = [boxPoint[0] - piFactor, boxPoint[1] - pjFactor]
  const pNormalLine = turf.lineString([pNormalLineEndA, pNormalLineEndB])
```

When I visualize the extended line ( `normalLine` ) and the perpendicular line to the extended line ( `pNormalLine` ) with geopandas, it produces:

[image: extended and perpendicular line]

The extended line is shifted to the right. The line that should be perpendicular isn't.

I expected the extended line to overlap the line segment and for the perpendicular line to be perpendicular. Additionally, I would expect the point of intersection to be at `a`.

I am not sure what is going wrong. I am guessing there is a fundamental concept I am missing.

What am I missing?

Comment: As the question is written, one has to guess from your code what are you trying to do. Please edit your question and explain in details: (1) "extend in both directions" How long should the extension be? (2) "draw the perpendicular line segment" Where? Anyway, the main problem is that you are using cartesian math for spherical [lng, lat] coordinates. You should be using turf functions far all the operations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Proposal from @Jan Šimbera to convert coordinates to projected CRS EPSG:32737 (UTM zone 37S) and then use cartesian math would in this case work quite OK, since line length is only about 20km and central meridian for EPSG:32737 is 39, very close to the line coordinates.

But much simpler and generally valid solution would be to use `turf.bearing` method to get line bearing and then `turf.destination` method to get coordinates of desired points.

Code could then look something like this (point offsets are one quarter of line length, see image below for meaning of points; code is JS, map by Leaflet):

```
var a = turf.point([-46.84417083099993, 37.821055535000085]);
var b = turf.point([-46.64967213299991, 37.89112389400009]);

var distance = turf.distance(a, b);
var bearing = turf.bearing(a, b);

var a2 = turf.destination(a, (distance / 4), (bearing + 180));
var b2 = turf.destination(b, (distance / 4), bearing);

var ap1 = turf.destination(a, (distance / 4), (bearing + 90));
var ap2 = turf.destination(a, (distance / 4), (bearing - 90));

var bp1 = turf.destination(b, (distance / 4), (bearing + 90));
var bp2 = turf.destination(b, (distance / 4), (bearing - 90));
```

That's how this would look like on the map:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. This is what I ended up doing to resolve the issue. I realized that turf's bearing and destination functions are what I needed.

Answer (score 2):

You are using planar geometry equations (Euclidean distance measurement, etc.) on spherical coordinates, which will introduce errors.

If your data only cover a limited geographical extent, try converting the coordinates to a planar coordinate system (such as [WGS84/UTM37S](https://epsg.io/32737) - check the linked page if the extent is sufficient), doing the calculations in those coordinates and then converting back. Geopandas make the conversions easy to do in a single function call.